# moving gwt 2.4 app to gwtp - good idea?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

i am working on a medium sized gwt app it uses MVP and activities/places, gin/guice. in the last month i am more and more disgusted by the many boiler plate classes/ much boiler plate code - writing a place that simply (de)serializes some parameters is a pain. Setting up activity mapper and managers is also only a matter of correct copying and pasting.

now i again stumbled across gwtp and read some wiki pages. I think with it i could delete many classes on client side.

but is it a good idea to migrate a project to gwtp at this state? does anybody has experience with such an migration? could activities/places/boiler plate coexist with gwtp stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the size of your app, it may require a lot of work. If you're not used to GWTP, I don't suggest to do that yourself until you're used to do it.

I've personnally done it on several projects, small, medium to large size and it can be done, but it needs that you understand the workflow perfectly.

It can also live together with some existing code, we did that on a large scale project that had a lot of legacy code.

But I'm afraid that if you're not already a experienced user of GWTP, this will be a hard change to make by yourself.